# File watcher ignores other changes

Tags: phpstorm, file-watcher

PhpStorm is ignoring another changes when file watcher was triggered. I hope you will understand my problem.

For example, when I am trying to write "display: block;" File watcher only takes "display: blo;" instead of "display: block;"

Comment: Show your file watcher settings.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/b87uk1 E: Thanks for response, i just found the problem. :)